# LLVM IR for addition and subtraction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I use "builder->CreateSub" and "builder->CreateAdd" to generate LLVM-IR for subtraction and addition.

```
        left = this->builder->CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(*this->llvm_context), nullptr, std::string("a1"));
        right = this->builder->CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(*this->llvm_context), nullptr, std::string("b2"));
        builder->CreateSub(left, right, "sub");
        builder->CreateAdd(left, right, "add");
```

However, the generated IR (shown below) cannot be compiled/interpreted by LLVM (lli)

```
 %a1 = alloca i32, align 4
 store i32 100, ptr %a1, align 4
 %b2 = alloca i32, align 4
 store i32 10, ptr %b2, align 4
 %add = add ptr %a1, %b2
 %sub = sub ptr %c3, i32 2
 %sub1 = sub ptr %add, %sub
```

Which gives error (on ptr):

```
 lli: lli: test.ll:14:14: error: invalid operand type for instruction
 %add = add ptr %a1, %b2
```

Comment: `add` and `sub` work with integers, but you're giving them pointers (or, in the second case, one pointer and one integer). It is unclear from your question whether you meant to dereference those pointers first or whether you wanted to perform pointer arithmetic (though I don't see a use case for adding two pointers, so I'm guessing at least one of those wasn't meant to be a pointer). Please clarify what you're trying to do and post a [MRE].

Comment: Thanks, I added more details. a1 and b2 are LLVM alloca (registers). How two registers should be added in LLVM?

Comment: The C++ code you posted does not involve any allocas. Your LLVM assembly is clearly not being generated by that code. Anyway, alloca gives you pointers. If you want to add the pointed-to values, you need to dereference (load) the pointers first.

Comment: My mistake. Modified again. Thanks for the comment about "load". I wonder why and when this load is needed? This seems like adding 2 registers. Why it should be complicated.

Comment: You need the load because you have allocas. The alloca instruction means "give me bytes of memory on the stack" and %a1 and %b2 are pointers to that memory. The load instruction reads the memory that pointer points to. If you had registers and not allocas, you could just use "add" directly, since add only works on registers. Add just adds, it doesn't also read memory.

Comment: Thanks, using load, it works and I understand it better. One last question; we need load since we need to bring data from stack to registers and then use math operations. Similar to what happens in CPUs (registers and ALU)?

Comment: The question of "what does a CPU do" depends entirely on the CPU. We can roughly split CPUs into RISC (reduced instruction set) and CISC (complex instruction set) and on many CISC, x86 included, the operands to an "add" may refer to registers or to memory. Contemporary CISC CPUs are generally RISC machines implementing a CISC instruction set as a "microcode" program, turning a complex add into load/load/add/store as needed.

Comment: One last thing, similar to CPUs, LLVM has no "address of" operation, there's no address of a register, just like on CPUs. When lowering C variables to LLVM IR it is common to use an alloca, just in case the C code happens to write "&val" in which case an LLVM frontend would use the AllocaInst itself as that pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Nick Lewycky, we need load instruction to read memory from stack where alloca vars are stored. I added CreateLoad for left and right variables above.

```
builder->CreateLoad(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(*this->llvm_context), alloca);
```